# How do I make an SQL query in Postgres that finds total balance and applies credit fees for the year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am totally new to Postgres and I cant find any example of what I am trying to do...

I have a table of transactions for a year:

amount | date

```
12     |  1980-02-12
-200   |  1980-03-06
30     |  1980-03-14
```

Positive transactions for incoming money.

Negative transactions for credit payments.

And I need to return a total for the year that also reflects charging a $20 fee for every month where less than $400 in credit was used, like so:

```
total
-------
80,401
```

My thought was that I would first find total credit for all months like this...

```
WITH month_credit_totals 
AS
(SELECT 
    SUM(amount) AS total_credit 
FROM transactions 
WHERE amount < 0
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', date))
```

and from there I would find the amount of months with less than $400 in credit payments like this...

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM month_credit_totals
WHERE total_credit <= -400
```

I wanted to save off this number, subtract it from 12, multiply that result by -20, and get the total amount owed in credit fees for the year that way.

Then, I thought I could just total up the `amount` column, apply that total fee amount, and that would be my result.

But I am having so much trouble understanding the syntax as a complete beginner, I cant find a way to save off variables, do the math, and apply that to total. I am constantly getting syntax errors that are pointing me in no direction just when I try to declare a variable at all.

Maybe I'm going about this the completely wrong way?

I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you don't really need to save these variables anywhere, just calculate it on the fly.

```
WITH credit_by_month AS
(
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', dt), SUM(amount) AS total_credit
  FROM transactions
 WHERE amount < 0
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('month', dt)
)
SELECT COUNT(*) * 20 AS credit_fee
  FROM credit_by_month
 WHERE total_credit > -400
```

[Here's a working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f9ed2ed646efc14013256816bec6c0c3), it's using random data so it will return a different number every time.